# I have a grid in a tab within a tabpanel. how do I refresh the grid in the open tab?

Tags: grid, extjs4, tabpanel

What if I have a grid in an open tab within a tabpanel and I want to refresh the grid content WHILE THE TAB IS OPEN. How do I go about refreshing the grid content?

I have a tab panel and each new tab contains a grid. In any open tab I can make changes to the grid content within that open tab, BUT in making these changes sometimes the changes may include content with an already open tab other than the tab I am working on that has a grid within it. How do I then go about refreshing the grid content within another open tab?

Currently I have to close the open tab and re-open it to see the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Does reloading the other open grid's store not work some reason? That would be the normal thing to do I think. E.g.:

```
var grid = theOtherOpenTab.down('gridpanel');
grid.store.load();
```

If the other grid's store *is* being updated but it is not rendering for some reason you could try one of these:

```
var grid = theOtherOpenTab.down('gridpanel');
grid.doComponentLayout();
```

or

```
var view = theOtherOpenTab.down('gridview');
view.refresh();
```

Comment: But... If I have three open tabs and I update the content in the active tab, how do I "refresh" the content in each of the OTHER open tabs, instead of my having to close the tabs to do a new call to the data source to update the tab view for all tabs?

Comment: My concern is not refreshing the data in the active/open tab. After I write the changes to the database within the open/active tab, I am able to do a "refresh" within the store, with a listener for a 'write' action. I just do a store.load(); I WANT TO REFRESH <ALL> OTHER OPEN TABS